# Twitter Intent Callback

Tags: javascript, twitter, callback, widget

I'm having some issues with attaching a callback to a tweet.

I have a link:

```
<a id="shareLink" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet</a>
```

First, I get this error in Firebug, simply from loading widget.js:

```
uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for
<http://platform.twitter.com> to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger
```

Regardless, it does do the pop up, and tweets, successfully.

Moving on, I add this code:

> twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
>
> ```
>  alert('YES');
> ```
>
> });

Now everything breaks. In Firebug I get this:

```
a is null
```

With a reference to the first line of widget.js

```
(function(a,b){function s(a){for(var b...cument.body.firstChild);return c})});
```

What the hell? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does it break only in firefox/firebug?

Comment: no, it fails in chrome and safari as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a Twitter bug. See this thread:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4315

Sounds like it should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [firebug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=4991) issue. It appears to have been fixed in Firebug 1.9b2.

Comment: yep, i was asking because Iv'e been getting the same behavior in firefox/firebug since a couple of days ago. But he says it fails in chrome and safari too.